# Looping through a pandas dataframe and append the rows to other dataframes depending on True/False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Simple question, first time i am using pandas, but still could not find an answer googling.

I have this dataframe info.

```py
info.head
artist in_train new_filename
0 Barnett Newman True 102257.jpg
1 Barnett Newman True 75232.jpg
2 kiri nichol False 32145.jpg
.
.
.
```

Now i want to create two new dataframes and adding rows from info to them depending on if the column in_train is True or False.

```py
train_info = pd.DataFrame(columns=('artist', 'filename'))
test_info = pd.DataFrame(columns=('artist', 'filename'))

for index, row in info.iterrows():
  if row["in_train"] == True:
    train_info.append(row[["artist", "new_filename"]])
  else:
    test_info.append(row[["artist", "new_filename"]])
```

For some reason this code assigned all rows in info to test_info and nothing to train_info.
How do i solve this?

Comment: Hello is in_ train column of type bool? I think you should add True between "

Comment: Yes i have tried that, but then i checked and:  info.dtypes:  in_train  bool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iterrows` is [generally not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/8366805) in `pandas`, you can solve it quite simply with masking

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'artist':np.random.randint(0,10,10),
                   'in_train':np.random.randint(0,2,10).astype(bool),
                   'new_filename':np.random.rand(10)})

train_info = df[df['in_train']].drop(columns='in_train').reset_index(drop=True)
test_info = df[~df['in_train']].drop(columns='in_train').reset_index(drop=True)
```